# How does this method determine to use the given string or not. `GetConnectionString(connectionString ?? "Default")`

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, npgsql

Im creating creating a DataSourceFactory to be able to easily pass in a TestContainers connection string to test the Service file. I got this to work but Im having trouble how this is actually working.

```
public interface IDataSourceFactory
{
    NpgsqlDataSource Create(string connectionString);
}

public class DataSourceFactory : IDataSourceFactory
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public DataSourceFactory(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    // HERE
    public NpgsqlDataSource Create(string? connectionString)
    {
         connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString(connectionString ?? "Default");
        return NpgsqlDataSource.Create(connectionString ?? throw new InvalidOperationException());
    }
}
```

```
public class MealService : IMealService
{
    private readonly NpgsqlDataSource _dataSource;

    public MealService(IDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory, string connectionString = "Default")
    {
        _dataSource = dataSourceFactory.Create(connectionString);
    }
    
    public async Task<int> InsertMealEntryAsync(MealEntryCreateModel mealEntryCreateMealEntry, int userId)
    {
        const string sql = """
                           INSERT INTO "MealEntry"(name, user_id)
                           VALUES (@name, @userId)
                           RETURNING id;
                           """;

            await using var command = _dataSource.CreateCommand(sql);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", mealEntryCreateMealEntry.Name.ToString());
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", userId);

            var insertedId = await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();

            if (insertedId == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Meal entry insertion failed.");
            }

            return Convert.ToInt32(insertedId);
    }
```

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDataSourceFactory>(new DataSourceFactory(builder.Configuration));
```

```
public class MealServiceIntegrationTests : IAsyncLifetime
{
    private readonly PostgreSqlContainer _postgres = new PostgreSqlBuilder()
        .WithImage("postgres:15-alpine")
        .Build();

    private readonly IDataSourceFactory _dataSourceFactory;

    public MealServiceIntegrationTests()
    {
        var dataSourceFactoryMock = new Mock<IDataSourceFactory>();
        dataSourceFactoryMock.Setup(f => f.Create(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns((string connectionString) => NpgsqlDataSource.Create(_postgres.GetConnectionString()));
        _dataSourceFactory = dataSourceFactoryMock.Object;
    }

    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        await _postgres.StartAsync();
        
        const string createTableSql = """
                                      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "MealEntry" (
                                          "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                                          "name" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                                          "user_id" INT NOT NULL,
                                          "created_at" timestamp without time zone default (now() at time zone 'utc'),
                                          "modified_at" timestamp without time zone default (now() at time zone 'utc')
                                      );
                                      """;

        await using var dataSource = NpgsqlDataSource.Create(_postgres.GetConnectionString());
        await using var command = dataSource.CreateCommand(createTableSql);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    public async Task DisposeAsync()
    {
        await _postgres.StopAsync();
    }
}
```

So given the code provided I understand that If no string is passed it will use "Default" key and use that to check my `appsettings.json`  for a connection string. On the other hand when used like this

```
NpgsqlDataSource.Create(_postgres.GetConnectionString()));
```

Wouldn't that just use that given string to look in my appsettings.json because of this

```
    public NpgsqlDataSource Create(string? connectionString)
    {
         connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString(connectionString ?? "Default");
        return NpgsqlDataSource.Create(connectionString ?? throw new InvalidOperationException());
    }
```

So how does it know to just skip it and create the NpgsqlDataSource with the given string.

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you please be more explicit ?  if your question is about NpgsqlDataSource.Create(connectionString ??  maybe you should take a look at this page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator

C# the coalscing operator to check if a value is null or not.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to follow what you're asking but there's a difference between looking up a connection string as a key in a setting file and an actual connection string. Seems like you want something more like this:

```
public NpgsqlDataSource Create(string? connectionString)
{

     if (connectionString == null)
        connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("Default");

    return NpgsqlDataSource.Create(connectionString);
}
```